# How to improve CountDownTimer delay in Android App?

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, delay, countdowntimer

I am writing timer application (like the one we use for cooking) for android. I used `CountDownTimer` to decrease remaining time every second. However, because I am so new at Threads, I didn't know there was a delay in the timer.

For example, consider simple code using `CountDownTimer`:

```
CownDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         System.out.println(millisUntilFinished);
     }
}
```

When I run this, `onTick()` method should run 60 times, but it doesn't. Instead, it runs about 57 times. I found out that this is due to delay. What is the most accurate way to write my timer application? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Actually `onTick` is *synchronous* and would not do a next tick till the ongoing is complete. So if you are doing anything in onTick, it would take time to run it and those accumulated run-times are what causing the delay to total ticks

Comment: @Waqas thanks. that's the point i was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(60*1000, 1000) {
>     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         Log.e("", "millisUntilFinished"+millisUntilFinished);
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onFinish() {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     }
> };
> timer.start();
> ```

I run this code and on logcat i get 59 entries and I think 1 entry not get because when it  you stat timer it wait 1000 milies for first also and then go with onTick(),so the code is working fine

Thanks